# Should we ask for the OP's region when asking help for "rare" errors?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I found a question showing some Eastern Europe characters, more specifically [the word *code* in Serbian](https://www.google.com/search?q=translate%20code%20to%20serbian) about an exception error that is very likely to be a platform glitch, in this specific case the question is about the [Google Apps Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script) error "The document is inaccessible". I think  that it's a glitch, because I had the same error multiple times and usually retrying again or using an exponential backoff algorithm is enough.

As Google and other companies have data centers in several *international* regions and are censoring or being censored as a result of international politics (be it wars, firewalls, or other reasons), is it OK to ask for the OP's region in order to see if they might be affected directly or indirectly by them?

Comment: Of course. If it's info needed to debug the problem, we can't know it if OP doesn't provide it off the bat and we don't ask.

Comment: I think your question is too specific. I would ask "Is it ok to ask for user's locality when it might be relevant to the question they asked?". Sharing the location can be considered sensitive information even when there is no war.

Comment: Is it relevant to explain what's wrong? if it's a standard backoff error, that can be explained without getting into geo-politics.

Comment: When the conflict ends, wouldn't it be helpful to know that the problem was specific to only a certain place in the world? If so, then I think putting that information into the question is mandatory now.

Comment: You're asking about region-related blockages or outages. It doesn't matter what the current events are, the answer is the same.

Comment: @kaya3 That seems sensible, but if the region is the cause, then what? Should the author delete the question? But then we can conclude that the OP is in that region. This still may leak information.

Comment: @SebastianSimon If the problem is caused by temporary service outages, then normally the question should be closed as it is unlikely to benefit future readers in the long term. For outages that might potentially last for a long time, though, I'm not sure. Maybe that should be a separate question.

Comment: @Dharman Do you really mean  _"mandatory"_? That implies (to me) that such questions that don't provide location information automatically become fair game for downvoting and closing. So SO would need to put that in formal documentation for it to become a policy, and I can't see that happening. Or am I completely misinterpreting your comment?

Comment: @skomisa If a question is missing crucial details that would allow it to be answered then it should be closed.

Comment: @kaya3 I don't think you can make a blanket statement about whether or not an issue related to an outage would be helpful or not. I can't think of any explicit examples at the moment, but I know I've been here for dozens of vague error messages that seemed like client errors but turned out to be related to server/service side issues

Answer (score 108):

I don't see any need to ask their region; just say something like *"depending on your region, your problem might be caused by current outages in [place]. Have you checked the service status in your region to make sure that's not the problem?"*

So my advice in general is, don't ask somebody their region, instead give them the information that might make their region relevant, and let them check that for themselves without having to divulge potentially sensitive personal information. Besides not asking for personal information, this may also resolve the issue with less back-and-forth commenting.

If despite the above, there is some specific case where you really need to know somebody's region in order to help them, then you should at least explain why it might be relevant when you ask. This will hopefully avoid the other person taking your question the wrong way. That said, I can't think of any situation where you really *would* need to ask.

Comment: Thanks. The question that inspired this question finally was a simple glitch (no OP location required). Now I think that when the issue looks to be related to the OP location we should point them to check the service status in their region to the company managed support / dev relationship channels (issue trackers, twitter, etc. depending on each company)

Comment: I would also say, because some of us are contractor, sometimes working remotely **your** region doesn't make much sense, maybe they are on said region because this region is the closest to the end-users, regardless of the region of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The geographic region is a relevant technical aspect, especially when it comes to cloud computing (this may not necessarily be the user's geographic region, but from where the execution is being requested and where it is being executed).

[Petal Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petal_Maps) also wouldn't let me request the default Chinese example coordinates, when requesting from Europe. And with a few Android vendors, Mainland China and rest of world is kind of different.

And there's also these embargoed country user questions, e.g., when it comes to repositories. Under US export regulations, such proxy questions might even count as illegal - because it may circumvent these export regulations.